# Applying a filter function to Mapstruct generated mappings

Tags: mapstruct

I'm trying to work around an issue where MapStruct loads all the JPA references in my object (even though they are specified as FetchType.LAZY).

I've added a method to my mapper that gets 'called' for each method, except for the ones that I really want it called for which are the getters for any 'used' mappers)
The method I have created on the top level mapper interface class is as follows:

```
default <T> T checkIt(T o) {
    return o;
}
```

and the generated code is as follows for the mapping method I am using:

```
customerOrderDto.setStartDate( checkIt( customerOrder.getStartDate() ) );
customerOrderDto.setEndDate( checkIt( customerOrder.getEndDate() ) );
customerOrderDto.setCustomer( customerDtoMapper.toDto( customerOrder.getCustomer() ) );
customerOrderDto.setTopology( topologyDtoMapper.toDto( customerOrder.getTopology() ) );
```

As you can see, it generates it for the first two (Start & End Date) but for the other two (Customer & Topology) which have their own mappers defined (and are used by this mapper) it doesn't call it.

Is there any way to get MapStruct to call this for each method it does a 'get' on?

If I can get it to wrap each .get() method I should have a chance to check whether the entity has been loaded yet, and also potentially filter it using a @JsonView view mapping.

Answer (score 0):

First of all MapStruct does not load any JPA references. MapStruct is an annotation processor tool that generates Java code which you then use to perform the mapping.

The `checkIt` method is not being used because there is a more specific method that can be used to perform the mapping (in `customerDtoMapper` and `topologyDtoMapper`). On top of that MapStruct does not perform mappings when it passes the mapping to other methods. Your method will also only work when mapping between same source and target types.

However, what you could do is to perform the needed check in your other mappers such as `customerDtoMapper` and `topologyDtoMapper`.

What you can do is use the new `@Context` possibility and `@BeforeMapping` methods that return a non-null value back (which is then immediately returned from the method). The `@Context` can be used to check in your `customerDtoMapper` whether a check needs to be done.

You can try making your `checkIt` method an `@BeforeMappingMethod`. You will however need to change the signature as your are trying to return some kind of DTO and not the passed source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm aware that MapStruct doesn't load JPA references, it was just to define my particular use case. It's not possible to add the check to the other mapper as at that point it's too late - the act of calling the "getCustomer()" method has already invoked the Javassist proxy to load the entry from the database, and from my understanding this also rule out the @BeforeMapping option too. What would be really nice is to be able to get to a point where what is actually generated is as follows: "toDto( myFunc (oDest, fDest, () -> customerOrder.getCustomer() ) )" as that would ..

Comment: ... also allow me to check the destination field Field to see if it has any JsonView annotations and filter that as well based on a passed-in Context (another issue I currently have with MapStruct). The myFunc would need to be defined as myFunc(Object oDest, Field fDest, Callable<T> getter) where I could check whether (a) the Javassist proxy has been initialized and return null if not (JPA use case 1) and (b) check the destination field for a JsonView annotation and return null if not in the set of required views (JsonView use case 2) ...

Comment: ... If I wanted the object returned I would just do a "return getter.call();". The MapStruct codebase is large so if anyone could point me at where I would look to make the changes it may help. Thanks.

Comment: Theoretically what you are trying to achieve might be done by using [source presence checks](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#source-presence-check). However, this would mean that you will need to add a lot of checks like that in your entities. By the way, don't get me wrong, I didn't meant my initial sentence as an attack (just wanted to clarify for other readers as well). Your use case is interesting, but that would go against the core of MapStruct (no reflection)

Comment: Thanks again Filip. No worries about the JPA point, I didn't take it as an attack at all ;-) I totally agree that MapStruct shouldn't break its principles but it would be nice if there was a way of allowing a developer to hook into the lifecycle more easily, and it's then up to them to break the rules if it suits them. I've seen comments asking for JsonView support and I think by optionally providing something like I describe (a reference to the destination object and the mapped field, as well as a Callable rather than the result of that callable) it could potentially help a lot of people?

Comment: The hook you are talking about should happen during compilation time and that can in theory help people do something (generate different kind of code). Feel free to bump an already existing issue or create a new one in the tracker. I also get your point as well. If you have a control over the places where you do your callings, you can in theory have a custom method that would direct to the correctly setup (with ignores) mappings in MapStruct

Comment: Thanks for your help Filip. I have added a new issue in the tracker at https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1327